# Why can't I use tkz-fct package to draw multiple function images at the same time?

Tags: tkz-fct

The following is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \tkzInit[xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymax=2]
    \tkzGrid
    \tkzAxeXY
    \tkzFct[color=red,domain=0:2]{2*x**2/(x**2+1)}
    \tkzFct[color=blue,domain=0:2]{x**2}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is:
[image]

So why only one plot is displayed here?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Welcome! I fail to reproduce your observation. When I compile this I get both plots, the blue one as shown in the screen shot, and an additional red plot.

Comment: I have the two plots too!. You don't need to call Tikz ! What is your version of tkz-fct?

Comment: @AlainMatthes the package tkz-fct is the latest version, I don't know if there is problem with the way of compilation, I use XeLaTeX

Comment: I use `pdflatex`  `xelatex` and `lualatex`. I compile the documentation with `lualatex`. I create `id` only to use other macro (for example to place a point)

Comment: You must allow Latex to launch gnuplot, otherwise the tkzfct.gnuplot file contains only the last function and when you launch gnuplot in the terminal, you get the table of a single function. Try pdflatex --shell-escape nameourfile.tex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you every one, I have solved my problem by adding `id=n` to the options of `\tkzFct`, and `n` is the number of function, as shown below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \tkzInit[xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymax=2]
    \tkzGrid
    \tkzAxeXY
    \tkzFct[id=1,color=red,domain=0:2]{2*x**2/(x**2+1)}
    \tkzFct[id=2,color=blue,domain=0:2]{x**2}
    \tkzFct[id=3,color=yellow,domain=0:4]{(2+x**2)/(exp(x))}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is:
[image]

Thanks for again!!